# Error: no 'dimnames' attribute when trying to assign to array

Tags: arrays, r, assign, named

```
`function(trans,initprob,N)'
{
  BrokerPosition <- c("BP", "IP", "SP")
  mysequence <- character()
  firstposition <- sample(BrokerPosition, 1, rep=TRUE, prob=initprob)
  mysequence[1]   <- firstposition

  for (i in 2:N) {
    prevposition <- mysequence[i-1]
    probabilities <- trans[prevposition,]
    BPosition <- sample(BrokerPosition, 1, rep=TRUE, prob=probabilities)
    mysequence[i] <- BPosition
  }

return(mysequence)
}
```

This is a function made to simulate Markov chain , but whenever I run it I get the error no 'dimnames' attribute for array ,any idea why is this happening

Answer (score 2):

Your array 'mysequence' is character, so R is trying to find the row with rowname matching mysequence[i-1]. If you don't set rownames on 'trans', this will throw your error. Either use a integer value to select a row from trans, or set the rownames on trans, depending on what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Hi it did solve the first error but now I have another error Error in sample(BrokerPosition, 1, rep = TRUE, prob = probabilities) : 
  incorrect number of probabilities ..my matrix is a 9*3 matrix

Comment: `probabilities` should be a length 3 numeric vector describing the probability that an element in BrokerPosition will be sampled. Since you have 3 elements in `BrokerPosition` you need 3 elements in `probabilities`