# Error: no 'dimnames' attribute for array

Tags: r, for-loop, multidimensional-array, attributes

I am trying to fill a 4D array with a for loop and I keep getting the following error:

`no dimnames attribute for array`

There was a similar question already asked ([Error: no 'dimnames' attribute when trying to assign to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243051/error-no-dimnames-attribute-when-trying-to-assign-to-array)) but I did not really understand the answer, so any help would be very welcomed!.

My code:

```
   RESULTS1=array(0,dim=c(3,3,40,3)) 
dimnames(RESULTS1)<-list(c(1,2,3), c(1,2,3), c(1:40), c("J4", "NC", "ND"))
for(i in c("J4", "NC", "ND")){ 
    RESk=array(0,dim=c(3,3,40))
    M.sub<-subset(Markov.time, Grid.short==i)
    if(length(M.sub[,1])>1){ 

        for(x in 4:43){
            time.dep<-M.sub[,c(x,x+1)] 
            RESk[,,(x-3)]<-apply(apply(time.dep,1,FUN = (MC_Matrix)),1,sum) }}
    RESULTS1[,,, i]<-RESk
}
```

The function I am using:

```
MC_Matrix <- function(X) {
  n <- length(X)

  neg.neg <- 0
  neg.null <- 0
  neg.pos <- 0
  null.null <- 0
  null.neg <-0
  null.pos <- 0
  pos.neg <- 0
  pos.null <- 0
  pos.pos <- 0


  for (i in 1:(n-1)) {
    if ((X[i]<0) & (X[i+1]<0)) {neg.neg <- neg.neg+1}
    if (X[i]<0 & X[i+1]==0) {neg.null <- neg.null+1}
    if (X[i]<0 & X[i+1]>0) {neg.pos <- neg.pos+1}
    if (X[i]==0 & X[i+1]<0) {null.neg <- null.neg+1}
    if (X[i]==0 & X[i+1]==0) {null.null <- null.null+1}
    if (X[i]==0 & X[i+1]>0) {null.pos <- null.pos+1}
    if (X[i]>0 & X[i+1]<0) {pos.neg <- pos.neg+1}
    if (X[i]>0 & X[i+1]==0) {pos.null <- pos.null+1}
    if (X[i]>0 & X[i+1]>0) {pos.pos <- pos.pos+1}
  }
  A <- matrix(c(neg.neg,null.neg,pos.neg,neg.null,null.null,pos.null,neg.pos,null.pos,pos.pos),3,3)
  return(A)
}
```

A subset of my data:

```
Markov.time<-structure(list(Grid.short = structure(c(5L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("", 
"C7", "J2", "J4", "NC", "ND", "NG", "NH", "NK", "NM", "NN", "NO", 
"NR", "NS", "NT", "NU", "NX", "NY", "NZ", "SC", "SD", "SH", "SK", 
"SM", "SN", "SO", "SP", "SR", "SS", "ST", "SU", "SW", "SX", "SY", 
"SZ", "TF", "TG", "TL", "TQ"), class = "factor"), Site = c(49L, 
92L, 141L, 2619L), X1976 = c(1.255272505, 0, 0, 0), X1977 = c(-0.109144469, 
0, 0, 0), X1978 = c(-1.146128036, 2.100370545, 0, 0), X1979 = c(0.954242509, 
-0.595220567, 0, 0), X1980 = c(0.22184875, -0.550907469, 0, 0
), X1981 = c(0.146128036, 0.425968732, 0, 0), X1982 = c(0.15490196, 
0.187990482, 0, 0), X1983 = c(0.505149978, 0.270647367, 0, 0), 
    X1984 = c(-0.477121255, -0.692721055, 0, 0), X1985 = c(-0.425968732, 
    0.345233658, 0, 0), X1986 = c(-0.176091259, -0.014240439, 
    0, 0), X1987 = c(0.176091259, 0.293730757, 0, 0), X1988 = c(-0.380211242, 
    -0.127399335, 0, 1.301029996), X1989 = c(0.079181246, -0.181054679, 
    0, 0.352182518), X1990 = c(-0.77815125, -0.064457989, 1.278753601, 
    -0.040428657), X1991 = c(0, -0.22184875, 0.152610163, 0.391537517
    ), X1992 = c(0, -0.062147907, -0.431363764, -0.24089338), 
    X1993 = c(0, -0.072550667, -1, -0.348454646), X1994 = c(0, 
    -0.087150176, 0.301029996, 0.176091259), X1995 = c(0, 0.191885526, 
    0.653212514, -0.159700843), X1996 = c(0, 0.397940009, -0.176091259, 
    -1.431363764), X1997 = c(0, -0.146128036, 0.176091259, 0), 
    X1998 = c(0, -0.318758763, -0.051152522, 0), X1999 = c(0, 
    0.199572355, 0.138302698, 0), X2000 = c(0, -0.102662342, 
    0.162727297, 2), X2001 = c(0, -0.062147907, 0.375663614, 
    -0.585026652), X2002 = c(0, 0.09017663, -0.181843588, 0.423875743
    ), X2003 = c(0, -0.301029996, -1.096910013, -0.608400169), 
    X2004 = c(0, 0.588271707, 0.903089987, 0.131278915), X2005 = c(0, 
    0.099702913, 0.051152522, 0.370665924), X2006 = c(0, 0.208275942, 
    0.159700843, 0.191885526), X2007 = c(0, -0.336942552, 0.411101455, 
    -0.447158031), X2008 = c(0, -0.617299958, -0.077886776, -0.045757491
    ), X2009 = c(0, 1.063386979, -0.229674087, 0.031034234), 
    X2010 = c(0, -0.102305045, -0.56427143, -0.383216752), X2011 = c(0, 
    -0.343781976, -0.954242509, 0.425968732), X2012 = c(0, 0.227798082, 
    0, -1.505149978), X2013 = c(0, 0.008773924, 0, 0), X2014 = c(0, 
    0.086359831, 0, 0), X2015 = c(0, -0.370356487, 0, 0), X2016 = c(0, 
    0.116505569, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Grid.short", "Site", "X1976", 
"X1977", "X1978", "X1979", "X1980", "X1981", "X1982", "X1983", 
"X1984", "X1985", "X1986", "X1987", "X1988", "X1989", "X1990", 
"X1991", "X1992", "X1993", "X1994", "X1995", "X1996", "X1997", 
"X1998", "X1999", "X2000", "X2001", "X2002", "X2003", "X2004", 
"X2005", "X2006", "X2007", "X2008", "X2009", "X2010", "X2011", 
"X2012", "X2013", "X2014", "X2015", "X2016"), row.names = c(14L, 
26L, 37L, 150L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would really appreciate a solution for this problem, as well as a simple explanation for a beginner of what was wrong.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I cannot run your code because it cannot find the object `Markov.time`.

Comment: It runs if I set `Markov.time` to your `structure(...)` from `dput`, provided I also set your x loop to 4:42.  But I have been unable to reproduce your "no dimnames" error.

Comment: I've just edited the question so as to set Markov.time there. The x loop setting was also another mistake I've just noticed, but the code is still not working for me :(

Comment: I suggest you do some tests to find out which line of code throws this error.

Comment: Try giving your dimnames explicit names, e.g. `dimnames(RESULTS1)<-list(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(1,2,3), c=c(1:40), d=c("J4", "NC", "ND"))`

Comment: Also, dimnames are character vectors, so try `as.character(1:3)`, etc, instead of of giving it numeric vectors that need to be coerced into character vectors.

Comment: The error must have been in the x loop, as the code is working now, and thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: That's good news.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running from 4 to 43 in your inner for loop, but your data seemed to have 43 variables, and x+1 is out of bound.

Can you try `time.dep<-M.sub[,c(x-1,x)]`?

This worked for me.

Comment: This worked fine for me as well, thanks, alternatively I just changed the bounds to 3:42. Such a stupid mistake, should have checked that before!